# Would people age differently at half the speed of light?

Tags: rockets

In my story, `the human race has decided to leave Earth and explore other planets. To do this, they invent the X-Zeus rocket, which travels at half the speed of light. What potential problems and/or notable effects would take place? My main question is: would they age at the same rate?

Comment: The title "**What would happen to a rocket** carrying people at half the speed of light?" does not match your main question "would they age at the same rate?"

Comment: "would they age at the same rate" as who?

Comment: @RonJohn As they would in a normal environment

Comment: To those travelers, the rocket *is* "a normal environment" (if for no other reason than we need "a normal environment" to survive).

Comment: Or do you *really* mean, "would people on the rocket age at the same speed as people on Earth"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it clearly lack basic research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will age at the same subjective rate: i.e. they won't have an experience of aging faster or slower than time generally seems to be passing for them.  Their minds and their bodies occupy the same frame of reference, so they must experience the same passage of time.

Where time dilation effects become noticeable is when you compare two frames of reference (for example, Earth and a rocket that leaves Earth.)  If I go out on a rocket and return, if my rocket is fast enough, I may age less than the people on Earth did during my absence, but I won't get extra years of life in the deal.  On the other hand, if I leave Earth on a rocket and you follow me with the same velocity and flight plan, we will have aged at the same rate.  Same trip, same effects.

Also, travel at half the speed of light is only going to cause mild time dilation effects.  If you take a 10-year round-trip in a rocket traveling at 50% light speed, when you return to Earth you'll find that the people on Earth report that about 11 1/2 years have passed during your absence.  Time dilation at different velocities can be found by the equation $t=$ $t_0\over\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$, where $t_0$ is the subjective time experienced in the moving frame, t is is the subjective time experienced in the comparison frame, v is velocity of the moving frame, and c is the speed of light.  $t$ will always be larger than $t_0$, the unaccelerated frame of reference always has "faster time."